# Regex Match throwing exception with my pattern

Tags: c#, regex, match

I'm calling match below but I'm getting an exception that says "Internal error in the expression evaluator." when I try and pass "*_sales.txt" in as config.FileNamePattern. For some reason it doesn't like this pattern. What am I doing wrong? I tried passing it in with and without the '@' symbol.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(Path.GetFileName(file), @config.FileNamePattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Because you passed an invalid regex. It cannot start with a quantifier. Try `@"_sales\.txt$"`

Comment: and `*_sales.txt` isn't a valid pattern anyways. `*` is a quantifier, and you have nothing for it to quantify. `.*sales.txt` would be valid.

Comment: Actually, I do not think the question is related to wildcards, just `*` was used as an incorrect regex pattern since OP thought it could be used as a regex, too.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `Regex.Match` is a regex pattern. You pass `"*_sales.txt"` that starts with a `*` that you think is a wildcard, but in fact is a quantifier matching *zero or more occurrences*. It cannot quantifier the beginning of a pattern, it is an invalid regex.

You might want to use

```
@"_sales\.txt$"
```

to check if a string ends with `_sales.txt`. Also, adding `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` to your options can optimize matching the string from the end.

Note the `.` is escaped to match a literal dot.

Also, a verbatim string literal is the best way to define regex patterns as you only have to escape the special chars once.